# how to highlight display text in Yii2 menu widget

Tags: php, menu, yii2

I am using menu widget in yii2 to create side menu.
My menu contains two menu items which point to the same action. One link is used with parameter and another without parameter.
However, when I click on any of the link only link without parameter highlights. How can I highlight another link when clicked on?
My code for generating menu is :

```
dmstr\widgets\Menu::widget(
            [
                'options' => ['class' => 'sidebar-menu'],
                'items' => [

                    [
                        'label' => 'Leave',
                        'icon' => 'share',
                        'url' => '#',
                        'visible'=>  (General::ifUserPermitted('leaveCreate')||General::ifUserPermitted('leaveDeleteOwn')||General::ifUserPermitted('leaveReject')||General::ifUserPermitted('leaveSeeAllLeave')||General::ifUserPermitted('leaveTeamLeaveApproval')||General::ifUserPermitted('leaveViewOwn')), 
                        'items' => [
                            [
                                'label' => 'Create',
                                'icon' => 'creative-commons',
                                'url' => ['/leaveparent/create'],
                                'visible'=> General::ifUserPermitted('leaveCreate')
                            ],
                            [
                                'label' => 'View',
                                'icon' => 'address-book-o ',
                                'url' => ['/leaveparent/index', 'LeaveparentSearch[userName]' => common\models\Person::getFirstNameByUserId(Yii::$app->user->id)],
                                'visible'=> General::ifUserPermitted('leaveViewOwn')
                            ],
                            [
                                'label' => 'View All',
                                'icon' => 'address-book-o ',
                                'url' => ['/leaveparent/index'],
                                'visible'=> General::ifUserPermitted('leaveSeeAllLeave')
                            ],
                            [
                                'label' => 'Pending for approval',
                                'icon' => 'check',
                                'url' => ['/leaveparent/index', 'LeaveparentSearch[report_to_user_id]' => Yii::$app->user->id, 'LeaveparentSearch[status]' => 'Pending'],
                                'visible'=> (General::ifUserPermitted('leaveTeamLeaveApproval')||General::ifUserPermitted('leaveReject'))
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ]
            ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `active` configuration key in the item configuration you want to set active. It should return `true` when conditions are met. Something like:

```
'active' => Yii::$app->controller->id === 'leaveparent' 
                && Yii::$app->controller->action->id === 'index',
```